# hadoop copying the result from hdfs to S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-emr

I've successfully completed my job on Amazon EMR, Now I want to copy results from `HDFS` to `S3`,but I have some problem

this is the code (--steps)

```
{
    "Name":"AAAAA",
    "Type":"CUSTOM_JAR",
    "Jar":"command-runner.jar",
    "ActionOnFailure":"CONTINUE",
    "Args": [
        "s3-dist-cp",
        "--src", "hdfs:///seqaddid_output",
        "--dest", "s3://wuda-notebook/seqaddid"
    ]  
}
```

this is the logs:

> 2019-04-12 03:01:23,571 INFO com.amazon.elasticmapreduce.s3distcp.S3DistCp (main): Running with args: -libjars /usr/share/aws/emr/s3-dist-cp/lib/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar,/usr/share/aws/emr/s3-dist-cp/lib/commons-logging-1.0.4.jar,/usr/share/aws/emr/s3-dist-cp/lib/guava-18.0.jar,/usr/share/aws/emr/s3-dist-cp/lib/s3-dist-cp-2.10.0.jar,/usr/share/aws/emr/s3-dist-cp/lib/s3-dist-cp.jar --src hdfs:///seqaddid_output/ --dest s3://wuda-notebook/seqaddid 
>   2019-04-12 03:01:24,196 INFO com.amazon.elasticmapreduce.s3distcp.S3DistCp (main): S3DistCp args: --src hdfs:///seqaddid_output/ --dest s3://wuda-notebook/seqaddid 
>   2019-04-12 03:01:24,203 INFO com.amazon.elasticmapreduce.s3distcp.S3DistCp (main): Using output path 'hdfs:/tmp/4f93d497-fade-4c78-86b9-59fc3da35b4e/output'
>   2019-04-12 03:01:24,263 INFO com.amazon.elasticmapreduce.s3distcp.S3DistCp (main): GET http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/availability-zone result: us-east-1f
>   2019-04-12 03:01:24,664 FATAL com.amazon.elasticmapreduce.s3distcp.S3DistCp (main): Failed to get source file system
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: hdfs:/seqaddid_output
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$27.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1444)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$27.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1437)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:1452)
>       at com.amazon.elasticmapreduce.s3distcp.S3DistCp.run(S3DistCp.java:795)
>       at com.amazon.elasticmapreduce.s3distcp.S3DistCp.run(S3DistCp.java:705)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:76)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:90)
>       at com.amazon.elasticmapreduce.s3distcp.Main.main(Main.java:22)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:234)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:148)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the bug is caused by a race condition when CopyFilesReducer uses multiple CopyFilesRunable instances to download the files from S3. The problem is that it uses the same temp directory in multiple threads, and the threads delete the temp directory when they're done. Hence, when one thread completes before another it deletes the temp directory that another thread is still using.

I've reported the problem to AWS, but in the mean time you can work around the bug by forcing the reducer to use a single thread by setting the variable **s3DistCp.copyfiles.mapper.numWorkers** to 1 in your job config.

Comment: thanks,I found another way to save my results to s3, first I will getmerge the results to the master,then use "aws s3 cp ......" copy to the s3 , it like this:

Comment: {
        "Name":"save the results",
        "Type":"CUSTOM_JAR",
        "Jar":"s3://us-east-1.elasticmapreduce/libs/script-runner/script-runner.jar",
        "ActionOnFailure":"CONTINUE",
        "Args": [
            "s3://wuda-notebook/bash/save-results.sh",
            "--save-results", "s3://wuda-notebook/results"
        ]  
    }

Comment: this is the 'save-results.sh'                                                                                                                                          { hadoop fs -getmerge metric_output metric                                                                                                                                      aws s3 cp metric s3://wuda-notebook/metric}

Answer (score 0):

Well I had the same problem with the copy and the issue was because I was not adding the full path for the main path.

I was doing just like you:

```
s3-dist-cp --src hdfs:///my_path/ --dest s3://my_mucket --srcPattern .*\.parquet
```

And I got the exactly same error as you.
The solution is add the full path for the hdfs path:

```
s3-dist-cp --src hdfs:///user/hadoop/my_path/ --dest s3://my_mucket --srcPattern .*\.parquet
```